# Local Length Scale Kernel in Gaussian Processes (Nonstationary)

Tags: machine-learning, stationarity, gaussian-process

I've been working on Gaussian Processes and came across a rather nice local length scale kernel proposed in "Nonstationary Gaussian Process Regression Using Point Estimates of Local Smoothness" from ECML 2008. The idea is simple - to model non-stationarity you need varying lengthscales. The authors propose modelling the length scale itself as a GP over the input space, thus creating a hierarchical inference model, wherein you first learn the lengthscale as a function over your space and then you learn the target variable as a function over your space. It turns out that the predictive distribution is not analytically tractable and that the authors use some approximations for the same.

My question is the following:
a) If you are approximating the Log Likelihood with only the first level of inference, without even going into the second level, one could as well learn any ML algorithm, not specifically a GP to learn the lengthscale as a function of the space. Why model it as a GP afterall?

PS. I am just a beginner in Bayesian Machine Learning and do not have any expertise. I happen to learn a little bit about GPs from Rasumussen and Williams and found them interesting.

Comment: I am working with this kernel for a while. I believe (I might be totally wrong) that they choose GP to model the lengthscales (particularly RBF kernel) because of the assumption that closer lengthscales are likely to have similar values and also to allow infinite flexibility as GPs have. I am also interested in knowing how this kernel will behave if lengthscales are modeled using other ML algorithms. The possible problems can arise in defining the optimization function because authors consider the second level GP kernel into the optimization function. How would one define it if we use, let us

Comment: It is an interesting point that you raise here. 

However regardless of the algorithm we are doing optimization in the end. Maybe modeling one level as a simple neural network, and the other as a Gaussian Process could be more helpful? 

Also GPs are restrictive in terms of what they can capture given the RKHS equivalence. 

I'd assume that an alternating minimization scheme might help.